# ES6 - How to modify a variable in other modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

in module Global.js:

```
export let transLog = [];
```

in main:

```
import * as G from "./Global";
G.transLog = [];
```

I got a error:

```
app.js?c99e:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property q of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at eval (app.js?c99e:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap e92860b74eb6dd40b159:62)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e92860b74eb6dd40b159:19)
    at bootstrap e92860b74eb6dd40b159:62
    at bootstrap e92860b74eb6dd40b159:62
```

webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: "[file].map"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: './dist/app.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

So, how to modify a variable in other modules?

Comment: You don't. Why would you need to? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just export a function for that purpose: in the first module: `let foo = 3; export default function(x) { foo = x; };` and in the second `import alterFoo from './firstmodule'; alterFoo(4);` All of this is stock-simple OOP, only difference is we don't have to fake modules with objects and closures now that we have real ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot assign new values to exported variables, only the module itself can do that (and when it does, it can be pretty confusing, so I'd recommend to avoid this).

You can mutate exported objects though, e.g. `G.translog.push(…)` or `G.translog.length = 0`.